# Gremlin: Retrieve Path which includes edges with match

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop

I'm learning Gremlin-Tinkerpop and trying to make a query to retrieve Paths with queries using match clauses.

Graph Sample :

```
A : LabelA ----edge["rel1"]-- B1 : LabelB { prop1 : "val1" }
            |--edge["rel2"]-- B2 : LabelB { prop1 : "val1" }
            |--edge["rel3"]-- B3 : LabelB { prop1 : "val1" }
            |--edge["rel4"]-- B4 : LabelB { prop1 : "val2" }
            |--edge["rel5"]-- B5 : LabelB { prop1 : "val2" }
```

It is easy to retrieve paths including edges. like this

```
g.V().hasLabel("LabelA").outE().inV().hasLabel("LabelB").path()
```

But.. with MATCH, I can't retrieve 'edge'

```
g.V().match(__.as("lba").hasLabel("LabelA").outE().inV().hasLabel("LabelB").as("b")).path()
```

How can I retrieve paths including edges with MATCH? (without 'as')

```
g.V().match(__.as("lba").hasLabel("LabelA").outE().as("r1").inV().hasLabel("LabelB").as("b")).path()
```

Thank you.

Comment: When you say you cannot retrieve the edge - do you mean have it appear in the `path` result? If so, then in my quick test with TinkerGraph I do see edges in the result. Which graph database are you working with? In general I tend to avoid using `match` if what I want back is a path because with `match` the path will contain the complete evaluation performed by the step which is not normally what I want/need.

Comment: Exactly, path result with match. @KelvinLawrence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general I would not use a `match` step for this type of query but here are some examples. If you want the edge to appear in a `path` just use an `as` step to give it a label. I used the air-routes data set to generate these examples.

```
gremlin> g.V().match(__.as("lba").hasLabel("airport").outE().inV().hasLabel("airport").as("b")).path().limit(1)
==>[v[1],v[1],v[135],[b:v[135],lba:v[1]]]

gremlin> g.V().match(__.as("lba").hasLabel("airport").outE().as('e').inV().hasLabel("airport").as("b")).path().limit(
1)
==>[v[1],v[1],e[5120][1-route->135],v[135],[b:v[135],lba:v[1]]]
```

In cases like this one however, the `match` step is redundant and actually yields more in the `path` than you probably want. The better Gremlin way to do this is:

```
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel("airport").outE().inV().hasLabel("airport").path().limit(1)
==>[v[1],e[5120][1-route->135],v[135]]
```

Match can be handy in cases like this one (below) but even then you can also express this just using `where` steps (this finds routes that do not also have a return route back to the starting airport).

```
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('airport').
......1>       match(__.as('a').out().as('b'),
......2>             __.not(__.as('b').out().as('a'))).
......3>       select('a','b').
......4>         by('code').
......5>       limit(1)
  
==>[a:JFK,b:LCY]
```

This can also be done without using a `match` step

```
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('airport').as('a').
......1>       out().as('b').
......2>       where(__.not(out().as('a'))).
......3>       select('a','b').
......4>         by('code').
......5>         limit(1)    

==>[a:JFK,b:LCY]
```

In general, when using `match` it is likely to be more useful to use `select` than it is going to be to use `path` as for complex `match` situations with many conditions, the `path` will be long and full of stuff you probably are not interested in.

Comment: Thank you! I have added .as into whole relation in match.